# Does cp (copy) pre-allocate space with fallocate()?

Tags: linux, cp, file-copy

When copying large files (1-2 GB per file) between file systems, file fragmentation can happen if the destination file system is nearly full.

Our C++ application code uses `fallocate()` to pre-allocate space when creating and writing data files but I'm wondering how the linux copy command `/bin/cp` handles that.

Does `cp` just copy bytes or chunks of data in a loop (and let the file system deal with it)? Or does `cp` first call `fallocate()` or `posix_fallocate()` with the size of the source file?

I haven't found anything on this subject searching the internet.

The filesystem could be ext3, ext4, or xfs.

Centos 8.1, kernel 4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP

**EDIT I**

As background, the actual application reads a constant bit rate network stream and pre-allocates a file for N seconds of content. If the actual bitrate is higher, the file naturally grows. `ftruncate()` is called when the file is closed, which handles if the actual bitrate is lower. `cp` is only used to move those files between filesystems, hence my question.

And the reasoning for that is to avoid fragmentation. Without `fallocate` the file system will become increasingly fragmented over time. (Of course `fallocate()` doesn't completely prevent the problem but certainly mitigates it)

According to [Uninitialized blocks and unexpected flags](https://lwn.net/Articles/527373/), `fallocate()` results in "efficient" allocation of contiguous blocks (for most filesystems):

> The fallocate() system call is meant to be a way for an application to request the efficient allocation of blocks for a file. Use of fallocate() allows a process to verify that the required disk space is available, helps the filesystem to allocate all of the space in a single, contiguous group, and avoids the overhead that block-by-block allocation would incur.

So I was wondering if copying a large, heavily fragmented file ends up contiguous or fragmented at the destination.  Since `cp` doesn't use `fallocate()` to pre-allocate space then answer appears to be "possibly yes".

Comment: Preallocation has its drawbacks, too.  How does your application handle the situation where the file changes size while it's being copied?  If `cp` doesn't do preallocation, it doesn't have to deal with that situation - it just copies from the input file until there's no more data.

Comment: The actual application reads a constant bit rate network stream and pre-allocates a file for N seconds of content. If the actual bitrate is higher, the file naturally grows.  `ftruncate()` is called when the file is closed, which handles if the actual bitrate is lower. `cp` is only used to move those files between filesystems, hence my question.

Comment: @Danny The context you are giving is quite interesting and should probably be part of the question. That said, I believe your question about `cp` has been answered and I have offered you a working alternative with `dd`. You didn't react to any of the two answers, and only added the comment above. So what else are you expecting from us exactly?

Comment: @xhienne, was a busy weekend.  I've added additional context to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of `cp` provided by GNU coreutils [does use `fallocate`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/copy.c), but only to punch holes in files, not to pre-allocate space for copy targets.

There are a couple of mentions of adding support for `fallocate`, so it appears there were at least vague plans for something like this at some point.